# QGIS Intellisense in Visual Studio Code

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get QGIS API intellisense in VS Code IDE but it doesn't work.

I'm using QGIS 3.4 and Windows 10.
I followed the instructions from this link: http://gis-expert.com/wp/2018/10/15/how-to-setup-qgis-3-and-visual-studio-code-plugin-development-windows/

I'm using: VS Code 1.29.1, extensions: Python and PYQT Integration.

This is my bat file:

```
@echo off
path %PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\bin
path %PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\grass\grass-7.4.2\lib
path %PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt
path %PATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\Scripts
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
path %PATH%;C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts

start "VisualCode QGIS" /B "C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" %*
```

Python and PyQT intellisense are ok, QGIS not.
Can you help me?

Comment: If you want to do anything with python3, you should call py3_env.bat in your bat file. There is an example bat/template (python3.bat.tmpl) which shows how to do it. It's in osgeo4w\bin and i was able to call many ide's by changing just the last line.

Answer (score 5):

this is my .bat for VS Code try with this

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"

@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES

set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%PYTHONPATH%

cd /d %~dp0

SET VSCBIN=D:\Users\fran\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

call "%VSCBIN%\Code.exe" %*
```

I hope I help you

Comment: Thanks! This one is actually working for me (excluding IntelliSense). I've tried the usual "copy the existing batch file and swap whatever path for VS code". Like what Anita Graser had [posted](https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/03/stand-alone-pyqgis-scripts-with-osgeo4w/) for PyCharm, but it doesn't work for me. Python is not able to import qgis package. Perhaps explicitly pointing to OSGeo root does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running QGIS 3.82 and VSCode 1.37.1 on Windows 10, but had no luck with Fran's .bat file.

I've managed to get intellisense working with just the following entries in a .settings file and starting VSCode without a .bat

```
{
     "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.8\\apps\\Python37\\python.exe",
     "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
         "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.8\\apps\\qgis\\python"]
}
```

The above paths are for standalone QGIS installation, and obviously would need to be updated for an OSGEO4W install.

Comment: Thanks @OrdinaryOrange The following works for VSCode and QGIS 3.4 ltr:  {
     "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.4\\apps\\Python37\\python.exe",
     "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.4\\apps\\qgis-ltr\\python"]
}

Comment: When you say "in a .settings file and starting VS Code without a .bat" where do you put the .settings file?  In the workspace?  in the VS Code install directory?

Comment: Been a while, but according to my notes the above json should go into the settings.json file of VSCode

Comment: works like a charm in my VS CODE / QGIS combination: 
'''{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.32.0\\apps\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.32.0\\apps\\qgis\\python"

    ],
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.32.0\\apps\\qgis\\python"
    ]
}'''